# How to count number of nodes under selected user on specific Level?

Tags: php, mysql, c, linked-list, binary-tree

I have a MySQL database and I am storing user records in the table structure below

```
User_mst
-------------------
id
user_name
parent_id
left_id
right_id
position       (keyword "left", "right" as string)
node_level
```

I am storing user records in a binary tree structure, so that it means there is a maximum of 2 child nodes under each node (User).

From this structure, I want to create a function which has

**Input:**

```
1.user_id
2.level
3.position
```

And the **Output** should be :

Number of Nodes under given `user_id` on given `level` and on given `position`.

So e.g. if the function is like that below

```
get_nodes(3, 4, 'left');
```

Then it should return:
There are **X** number of nodes under User ID **3** on Level **4**

I think that I have to build a function that will process recursively though I would like  suggestions.

Please help me build this function. Use any programming language such as C, PHP etc.
I am just looking for the logic here.

Here is the SQL for Create Table and some sample Insert statements:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1218345/

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do the column `node_level` and the parameter `level` correspond? Your database table looks like a mix of an adjacency list model and a nested set+level information.

Comment: Thanks for putting your interest @VolkerK. 
node_level and level point to the same db field node_level. It is the level of the Nodes in the whole binary tree, so e.g. very first node which is called root node will have 0 level. After that 1..2..3 levels will come. I hope this helps.

Comment: And the parameter `level` of get_nodes() is supposed to be relative to the node identified by `user_id` or the absolute value in the complete tree?

Comment: You will simply have to compare level with node_level. As that will be globally relative to whole tree. Or let me know if I am missunderstanding

Comment: Hm, an example tree (preferably as sql INSERT statements) and some example queries + expected results would be helpful...

Comment: is it OK if I send you the SQL file with the database somehow as the table structure is different and bigger then I have shown here? I am just trying to make things easier for you :)

Comment: Here is the SQL including Create table and Insert statements :)
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1218345/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are just looking for the logic, then pseudo-C-code should be fine:

```
struct NodeStructure
{
  int ID;
  int leftID;
  int rightID;
  int level;
  ...
};

int countChildren( int nodeID, int level )
{
  NodeStructure * node = find( nodeID );

  if( node == NULL )
    return 0;

  if( node.level == level )
    return 1;

  return countChildren( x.leftID, level ) + countChildren( x.rightID, level );

}

NodeStructure * find( int nodeID )
{
  // SQL CODE:
  // SELECT * FROM User_mst WHERE id = nodeID;

  // if( /* node has been found */ )
    // fill NodeStructure
  // else
    // return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sdra but Where is the Level being used ?? as this thing I have already done what you have done here. The important thing I want is to get the count on Specific level